# pytz python DST data extraction

Tags: python, pytz

I need to extract DST data from an iCalendar application. That is, I need to extract date, time and offset of a timezone DST/nonDST switch timepoint. Would be amazing if I could get info too about the year that particular DST rule went live.

I know I could iterate over days/hours to calculate that information by hand, but I wonder if I could access to the Olson inner data somehow.

I can do C/ctypes, it that would be useful.

Comment: What is the relation between `iCalendar` and `pytz`? Do you need [`._utc_transition_times`](https://bugs.launchpad.net/pytz/+bug/1262657)?

Comment: iCalendar needs to define timezones details in the file, so I need to know those details. In concrete, when is the DST flag changes and by how much. And since what year. Check, for instance http://calendario.es.python.org/posts/20140403-valencia.ics

Comment: here's [`next_dst()` function that returns the next time a utc offset changes for a given timezone](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23046111/4279)