# Programmatically get the time at clock-change

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, dst

i am confused about timezone and countrys at time-changes. Carlifornia changes the time at 10am, NewYork at 7am.

How can i programmatically get informations when the time will change next in California?

Comment: Please read the [timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) and the [dst tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/dst/info).  If you have a specific programming question, please provide more details such as what programming language you are using, what you are attempting to achieve, and what you have tried so far.

Comment: I forgot to set the programming-language. `dst` was new to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find out DST transitions, you could access [Olson timezone database](http://www.iana.org/time-zones) e.g., to find out the time of the next DST transition, in Python:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from bisect import bisect
from datetime import datetime
import pytz # $ pip install pytz

def next_dst(tz):    
    dst_transitions = getattr(tz, '_utc_transition_times', [])
    index = bisect(dst_transitions, datetime.utcnow())
    if 0 <= index < len(dst_transitions):
        return dst_transitions[index].replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc).astimezone(tz)
```

e.g., in Los Angeles:

```py
dt = next_dst(pytz.timezone('America/Los_Angeles'))
print(dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z'))
```

Output:

```py
2014-11-02 01:00:00 PST-0800
```

or in a local timezone:

```py
from tzlocal import get_localzone # $ pip install tzlocal

dt = next_dst(get_localzone())
if dt is not None:
   print(dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z'))
else:
   print("no future DST transitions")
```